# Bayesian ANCOVA in R via jags

Tags: r, jags

I'm trying to implement a Bayesian ANCOVA that takes account of heteroscedasticity in R using JAGS. However, despite going through several tutorials of Bayesian simple regression and ANOVA, I can't understand how to prepare the file for JAGS. Here is my code so far:

```
y1     = rexp(57, rate=0.8)   # dependent variable
x1     = hist(rbeta(57, 6, 2)) # continuous factor
x2     = rep(c(1, 2), 57/2)   # categorical factor
groups = 2
n      = 57
# list of variables
lddados <- list(g=groups, n=length(x), y=y, x1=x1, x2=x2)

sink('reglin.txt') # nome do arquivo aqui
cat('
    # model
    {
      for(i in 1:n){
        mu[i] = a0 + a[i] 
        y[i]  = a0 + x1*a[ x2[i] ] + ε[i]
      }

      priors
      y ~  dgamma(0.001,0.01)
      for(i in 1:n){
        inter[i] ~  dgamma(0.001,0.001)
        coef[i]  ~  dnorm(0.0,1.0E-

        likelihood
        got stuck...
      }
    }#------fim do modelo
')
sink()
```

Comment: Are you trying to run JAGS from R? In that case it might help to take a look at the R2jags or rjags packages.

Comment: I'll also suggest the `runjags` package. It seemed more convenient to me, and more importantly, it can run in parallel.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. However, my problem is writing the Bayesian ancova model, not with using the packages. I already have certain familiarity with R2jags and could not find how to code an ancova model in none of the tutorials of these packages, or other tutorials in the internet.

Answer (score 0):

Im currently trying out ANCOVA using rjags myself...

From my understanding, I would test this (untested);

```
require(rjags)
require(coda)

model_string <- "
  model {
    for ( i in 1:n ){
      mu[i] <- a0 + a[x2[i]] + a3 * x1[i] # linear predictor
      y[i] ~ dnorm(mu[i], prec) # y is norm. dist.
   }

 #  priors
    a0 ~ dnorm(0, 1.0E-6) # intercept
    a[1] ~ dnorm(0, 1.0E-6) # effect of x1 at x2 level 1
    a[2] ~ dnorm(0, 1.0E-6) # effect of x1 at x2 level 2
    a3 ~ dnorm(0, 1.0E-6) # regression coefficient for x1 (covariate)
   prec ~ dgamma(0.001, 0.001) # precision (inverse of variance)

 }
"

# initial values for the mcmc 
inits_list <- list(a=0, b=c(0,0), prec=100)
# model, initial values and data in right format
jags_model <- jags.model(textConnection(model_string), data=data, inits=inits_list, n.adapt   = 500, n.chains = 3, quiet = T)
# burn-in
update(jags_model, 10000)
# run the mcmc chains using the coda package 
mcmc_samples <- coda.samples(jags_model, c("mu", "a", "a1", "a2", "prec"), n.iter = 100000)
```

Tell me if it works...

Recommended books; McCarthy M. Bayesian Methods for Ecology and Kruschke JK. Doing Bayesian Data Analysis